# Correct action for a repost of recent question

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Some (many) new users are impatient for an answer, especially if the assignment is due soon.

Whats the correct action when they repost the same question, perhaps reworking the text a little.  The close as Dupe reason says "...and has an answer" which is often **not** the case.  Same text is used in the prompt if you want to Flag it as a dupe.

I tried to search but most everything related to duplicates is the **other** kind of duplicate question (RegEx to parse HTML, NullReferenceException, etc).

Comment: Dupe the new one to the old one. Duping to a question by the same OP is exempt from the "must have an answer" rule. If they keep doing it they'll get themselves banned.

Comment: Thanks - there has been more of this lately (finals?).  I take it, the system sees the same user ID on both questions to work towards a ban?

Comment: Yep, dupe it and downvote.  (I've only run into one of these once in the past week, and hadn't seen any for months before that.  But I don't go looking for them.)

Comment: (I do, maybe once a month, run across two nearly identical "write my code for me" posts from (apparently) different users.  I usually tell them to talk to their classmates.)

Answer (score 7):

Questions that are duplicates should be close voted or flagged as such, no matter the circumstances.

Questions that are so obvious duplicates I often pair my close vote with a down vote for lack of research. I use that same line of reasoning for users posting the same question again because they failed to research why their first question didn't get answered. I have no problem when I find these kind of posts to head over to a chat room to verify if my duplicate vote is correct. The attention it gets might speed-up the close vote process.

When I'm in a good mood I leave a comment explaining that they should put effort in their original question, with a link to one of the many meta posts on the subject, for example this one: [Reasking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270193/reasking-a-question)