# Reasking a question

Tags: discussion, questions, edits, duplicate-questions

I asked a question and its been 3 days with no answers or even comments/questions yet. I feel that it won't be answered going forward even though its an "easy" question (it doesn't require debugging code or running efficiency tests or anything). I probably didn't word it as simply as I could have. So I'm wondering, maybe if I rephrase the title it might better attract the right group of experts. Or maybe if I shorten and reword the entire body of the question. But if I did both, the question would be over 70% different and have a different title and carry the stigma of already being ignored for 3 days.

Do I post a new question and delete the old one (since its essentially a duplicate and apparently no one cares about it)? 
or
 Do I knowingly post a (possible) duplicate, and leave the old one as it is?
or
 Do I do an edit overhaul and hope it gets attention despite its age?

The question in question: [Distributing weighted matrix rotations to bone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25481176/distributing-weighted-matrix-rotations-to-bone)

Comment: with more rep the correct way would be to setup a bounty

Comment: reading up on bounties.

Comment: basically you'd offer some of your rep as an incentive for your question to be seen more.

Comment: Why not link the question here, it will get some more attention and maybe someone will care answering... or downvoting... or upvoting... you know, the [meta effect](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect). I suggest you check the question to benefit from the effect.

Comment: Added the question to the question about the question.  I think it just needs to be simplified, probably drop all the glsl code block but the relevant equation and change the title to "weighting a bone matrix" or something. Also want to reword much of it.

Comment: "What are their standard solutions and upsides and downsides?" That's a bit broad. I'd expect it to be closed for that reason.

Comment: Its not as subjective as it sounds though. What I have is a method used in three separate sourced locations that has a clear problem and what I'm asking is how the problem is worked around.

Comment: Do I preemptively delete it? Or close it myself?

Comment: @gunfulker George didn't say it was subjective, he said it was too broad.  It's just asking for too much information.

Comment: Well, an acceptable answer would be something like: "assemble the matrix on the graphics card, the GPU can handle the overhead" or "normalize the weighted vertices distance from the rotation point, its fastest and easiest even though it has a singularity at 180 degrees rotation". Presumably this has been done differently somewhere for a good reason and an answer would only need reference it.

Comment: @gunfulker That may be what you want to see in an answer, but that's not what your question is asking.  That's what George is telling you.  You should make the question that you ask more specific, since what you actually want to see is more specific.

Comment: @gunfulker If you're "lucky" you'll earn a [tumbleweed badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/tumbleweed)!

Comment: Seriously... I feel like I should learn the topic in question just to try to answer it and help you.

Comment: See also: [Prevent/punish self-duplicates](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262929/3614835)

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå: You must be luck _and_ refrain from posting in meta.

Comment: Post it here and get the attention via meta-effect. _And you already did that_ !

Answer (score 34, accepted):

No, do not re-ask the question, whether or not you delete it.

You're more than welcome to edit the question if you can find ways of actually improving it.  You should not be making meaningless edits just for the sake of creating activity.

If you have at least 75 reputation points, you can put a bounty on the question to generate additional attention.

Comment: The actual drawback for the OP is, that putting a bounty needs some rep to give away at all. So the only hope stays that some altruistic helpful soul would do for them :P ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ He can earn the reputation if the answer is that important to him.

Comment: Suppose that I ask a question, poorly, because I misunderstand the problem. No one answers, because they couldn't understand the question. A week later, I learn more. Now I have a partially new question, though substantially incorporating the old question. Why shouldn't I post a new question? If you think I shouldn't post a new question, surely you can imagine similar situations in which you think I should. That's my point: There's a gray area here. "Post a bounty" is helpful, but doesn't help illuminate the gray area.

Answer (score 34):

I started a bounty for you.

You may ask why in the world would someone do that.
My simple answer is because I can.

Good luck.

Comment: And it gives you an Altruist badge.  :oP

Comment: @JohnnyBones Is it altruistic to do something altruistically to obtain the Altruist badge?

Comment: @mason - It's somewhat philanthropic to obtain the Altruit badge.

Comment: I appreciate it and I'm glad to have the chance to see a bounty in action.