# May I reask a downvoted question I've edited that hasn't been reassessed after my edit?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

I wrote a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34742429/how-do-you-add-an-upload-widget-to-a-bokeh-server-app) and admittedly messed up. It was downvoted, I modified it immediately, but the user who downvoted it hasn't responded and now I fear the downvote is deterring other people from visiting what I'm confident is now an acceptable question.

It has been less than a day so I accept I'm a bit unreasonably edgy since I need the answer and it seems like a simple question. But this begs the question, is there a set amount of time I should wait before I delete and reask the edited version of my question?

According to this: [Reasking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270193/reasking-a-question) I shouldn't reask a question and should instead place a bounty on it. My situation isn't exactly the same I think due to my edits not yet being reassessed after a downvote. Regardless, the issue here would still be of course that I have to wait two days before I can apply bounty (I will gladly, but can only wait till then - I'd really like to know if there is anything I  can do *right now*) and also that I doubt the meager bounty I can offer with my small reputation will really help much.

Comment: Just be patient.  Don't post duplicate questions.

Comment: First, don't re-ask the question.  It will get closed as a duplicate and probably annoy some people.  Also, I think I found your question (is it [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34742429/how-do-you-add-an-upload-widget-to-a-bokeh-server-app)?)  Assuming that is what you are talking about, that question is way too broad.  We aren't going to write or find you a tutorial.  You need to narrow that way down and possibly show what you have tried and where you are getting stuck before it could be a reasonably on-topic question.

Comment: Okay, I need high-level advice though. I don't even know if what I'm trying will be even remotely a fruitful. I might try and try and try and then post a question with someone just telling me my method is impossible. 

Programmers Stack Exchange and Software Recommendations would both be off-topic as tutorial recommendations are not permitted there. Is there a site for my question at all? 

But now I must also know... isn't *this* question a good match for stack overflow meta? I cant find any other like it and in fact I saw I was upvoted before I was downvoted. What am I doing wrong *here*?

Comment: Don't worry about voting on meta.  It usually just expresses someone's opinion on the topic.  It has no bearing on rep.  See [Voting on Meta is Different](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254108/downvotes-on-meta-are-confusing-do-they-really-mean-poor-post-quality-or-jus)

Comment: Regarding your question, no it really isn't a good fit.  First, try doing some research.  I know nothing about bokeh-server, but in about 3 minutes on google I found out it is build on top of Flask.  Then I googled how to do file uploads in Flask and came up with [this](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/fileuploads/).  Start there.  Try implementing what they have there.  Then after you get a file to upload, try feeding it into bokeh.  Whenever you get stuck, try and figure it out yourself.  If you can't, ask on SO and share what you have, what you are stuck on and what you have tried.

Comment: Problem with your question is that it is completely unsuitable for Stack Overflow. You can re-edit it all you want but that will not remove main issue.   It is too broad, asking for opinions and recommendations as well as tutorials. You need guidance, and SO is not meant for that. If you bump into specific programming issue that you need help with, then post your code, show what you are trying to do with some minimal examples, and where you are stuck. One step at the time.

Comment: [This is a really good post about voting on meta, in addition to the previously mentioned post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272617/4639281)

Comment: Yea, that should have been required reading for me before I post

Comment: Nice work in improving your question. As far as accumulated downvotes are concerned, there is no system in place that would notify downvoters that you edited your question. So those downvotes will probably stay. But overal question score is now positive and that is what matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the thing.  Dalija Prasnikar [already touched on this earlier](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314556/may-i-reask-a-downvoted-question-ive-edited-that-hasnt-been-reassessed-after-m#comment293618_314556), but the core issue with your question is that it's just not suitable for Stack Overflow.  No matter how much editing you do on this one, it won't ever be suited for the site - it's asking for something that's very broad (how do I upload a file using [insert technology here]), and the only practical way to turn that question around would be to ask a question if you were having trouble *while* implementing that functionality, not *before*.

There should be no penalty to you to simply remove the question.

Comment: I just read this after modifying my question. I think I am following your advice now though nontheless. Thank you for letting me know about there being no penalty to remove a question. This is something I did not know.

Comment: @DirkHaupt:  I'm impressed that you managed to turn it around.  Kudos to you!  There's no penalty in removing a question *without* answers, of course, but there's a fairly steep one in removing one with answers.  At this point, it didn't have answers, which is why I stated that.  Since you've modified your question to be more on-topic, I hope that it gets reopened soon.